# While texture painting, is there a way to limit the maximum opacity of the paint simmilar to the weight setting in weight paint mode

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am using a mouse to do try and paint an area, I have to zoom in on the area to be able to get the precision I need however as I have to move the camera multiple times to cover the whole area I can't paint in a single stroke and I Can't find a way to prevent the paint from different strokes from stacking creating darker patches of paint where the strokes meet. Is there a setting like the weight slider in weight painting mode that simply limits the maximum strength of the paint or some other way to prevent dark edges between strokes

Example:

[image]

Intended result:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to do what you want is to leave the blend mode set to mix, set your strength to 1, and use the brush color (not the strength) to give you the final appearance that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that no, you cannot set a threshold that will limit the full opacity of overlapping strokes - these strokes from your example are additive, so the overlapping area appears more opaque than the parts that do not intersect.

The better way to handle this is to use the Mask tool to paint your strokes using the visualization color of your choice and setting your strength to full with no pressure control, then inverting the mask and switching to the Fill tool and setting the strength to your desired transparency, and then you can get even fill across your whole mask.
[image]
[image]